# read a pixel of the screen(i.e. 1024*768 which you can see now)

Tags: c, desktop, pixel, framebuffer

in Windows XP, C programming language

I want to read a pixel of the screen(i.e. 1024*768 which you can see now) in fast way

I think the framebuffer is the solution.

so

I tried

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

SDL_Surface *screen;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 ) 
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to init SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    exit(1);
  }
  screen = SDL_GetVideoSurface();
  if ( screen == NULL ) 
  {
    exit(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

but the screen seems NULL

sorry for newb question

but could somebody let me know how to access framebuffer for reading a pixel?

any possible ways are welcome

Comment: Do you want to read from the desktop, or from the window you just created?

Comment: I want to read from the desktop. which I can see now(not only a window but also taskbar, etc) thank you!

Comment: The cool kids haven't used 1024*768 resolutions for more than 10 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SDL doesn't let you read the pixels of the desktop.  It abstracts away those features since they are non-portable (for example, what would it mean on a console or embedded device to read a desktop pixel?)  As a result, you will need to use the Windows API directly.  It has been a while since I've used windows, but at least a couple of years ago the process worked something like this:

1. Get the desktop device context.
2. Read the pixel from that.

For example, the code might look something like this (again roughly speaking, I don't use windows any more so I am not 100% here):

```
 HDC desktopDC = CreateDCAsNull("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
 int pixel=GetPixel(desktopDC, x, y);
```

Comment: +1. `GetPixel(0,x,y)` worked or me so far. I think it's because desktop is always the zero window.